# Is it true that$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}|_{y=0} = \frac{\partial f(x,0)}{\partial x}$?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

For any differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, does $\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}|_{y=0} = \frac{\partial f(x,0)}{\partial x}$ hold? I think it does (by trying several functions, e.g. $f(x,y)=\sin(x^y)$), but I am not sure how to prove this..

Comment: By definition, $\partial_x f$ is the function obtained by differentiating $f$ relative to $x$ while fixing $y.$ If you evaluate this function at $y = 0$ then you obtain, by definition, $\partial_x f(x, 0) = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x, 0).$ So yes, it is true. What makes me wonder is why would you think these two expressions are different?

Comment: What definition are you using for each side of your equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

When differentiating with respect to a variable, all other variables are treated as constants. Since you compute the derivative generally (i.e. for an unknown constant), you can simply apply specific values to that general derivative.

For example, if $f(x)=\lambda x$, clearly $f'(x)=\lambda$, and so for $g(x,y)=xy$ we have $g_x(x,y)=\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=y$ for any choice of $y$